# multiplayer text based game

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am trying to find a way to make a sort of text based multiplayer game only using HTML 5, CSS and JavaScript.

I can't find a way to have updating text so that when one user changes text it would update to all users so they can see it. For example, I want to create the game "apples to apples" so one person is the judge and each other person gets 7 cards and they pick one card to send to the judge, then that person picks the one that best suits the descriptive card.

I need it to work so that when it picks the judge it will change that person's "client" page to the judge's page and all other users' pages would have 7 random cards that they can send to the judge.

I need a way to link all the players pages together and have them update according to inputs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want different clients to communicate with each other, you'll need a server to handle the synchronization! Socket.io running on Node.js is a good way to do it. Read more about it here: http://socket.io/